# How to run django and angularJS into a single development server?

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, django, serve

I have a project where I am using Angular js to consume the API that I built with Django-Framework. Currently I have to start up the django api using django development server e.g.,  python manage.py runserver 192.168.0.185:8080' and then I have to start up the angular (this is my webclient) js server using 'python manage.py runserver 192.168.0.185:8000
' Is there any way I can setup my django project to to run and web client so that i will no longer be seperating the development server of api and web client . That when i run api server it will also include the web client. Any idea? . Thank you.

Comment: You can serve your angularjs application to the client by returning `index.html` on `/` at `192.168.0.185:8080`

Comment: @varunagarwal , can you pleaser further explain this sir ?

Comment: is that on my settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be straight forward,

1. In url.py , create a mapping

   `url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),`
2. In `views.py`

create a function (example):

```
@csrf_protect
@requires_csrf_token
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html', content_type="text/html")
```

3. In `index.html` , put `ng-app` and call the `angular.js` CDN and `js` files.

That should do the work.

> Make sure to use `{% verbatim %}` and `{% endverbatim %}` if you want to use `{{ }}` for angularJS variable interpolation. Because, Django also has the same symbol ( i.e : `{{ }}`) to render the variable on it's template files.

Comment: ill try this one

Comment: bro , the step 1 and 2 is this on the API side right?

Comment: @Mr.RajivKumar : Yes, those are `.py` files.

Comment: Can i show you the project ?so you can understand the structure?

Comment: anyways this is a test project

Comment: Ok, can u share more details on https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/191573/how-to-run-django-and-angularjs-into-a-single-development-server?tab=general ? I am in ofc. Will check once i get some time :)

Comment: can i have a minute?

Comment: i cant join the room , repuration is less than 20